# Direct stderr to a file over ssh

Tags: ssh, io-redirection, stderr

I am trying to execute a command on a local machine and direct the stderr to a remote machine over ssh. I cannot do

```
 ssh remote machine "command 2>stderr.log"
```

because the remote machine doesn't have the correct built to execute the command, and I have to run the command on my local machine. I haven't tried it yet but I am mostly positive that we can't do `2>ssh local machine /dir/stderr.log`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to run a command *locally* but save the stderr output to a remote log file.

Try *process substitution*:

```
local_command 2> >(ssh somemachine 'cat >logfile')
```

Here, `>(...)` is *process substitution*.  It creates a file-like object from the command in the parens.  So, `2>` redirects stderr to that file-like object, resulting in the output being saved on the remote machine.

Or, just use plain old redirection:

```
{ local_command 2>&1 1>&3 | ssh somemachine 'cat >logfile'; } 3>&1
```

Here, stderr is redirected to stdout so that we can pipe it to ssh.  So that stdout does not go to ssh, we redirect it to file handle 3.  At the end of the command, file handle 3 is redirected to stdout so that it appears on the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about tracking stderr of the process while it is running, then you can use a temporary local file
eg

```
#!/bin/bash

tmpfile=`mktemp`

trap '/bin/rm -f $tmpfile ; exit' 0 1 2 3 15

run_command 2> $tmpfile

if [ -s $tmpfile ]
then
  scp $tmpfile remoteserver:logfile
fi

exit 0
```

If you want "live" data then you have buffering problems; sending stderr over ssh may not be line buffered and so this whole concept may not be the best way of doing it.